# Issues with workbench moderation

Tags: workbench

I've installed workbench and tried to work with it. I followed the step-by-step instructions given in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nqWLrxH_4M&index=9&list=WL) and I was almost successful in creating the content and moderating it between the two kinds of user one is `Publisher` and the other is `content-creator`.

`Content-creator` creates the content and forwards it to `needs-review`, now the publishers gets the access to the content in the `needs-review` tab. And the moderation should be done between these two users.

Here, my issue is when the `content-creator` creates a content - he is unable to see his content in his profile (I mean either in '`MyContent`', '`MyDrafts`' and '`Needs review`'). And the same case with the other user (publisher)- the `Needs-review` tab looks empty even though there is some content created by '`content-creator`'.

To keep it short, `MyWorkbench` tab looks empty- the `Needs-review` tab, `MyContent` tab and `MyDrafts` tab are empty. The only way the content appears is in Content tab.

I'm not aware of `workbench` module, I've followed all the instructions given in the video. I'm missing any?? Please give your answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions carefully?, once again verify the permissions as mentioned in the video and that should work.

Comment: In the workbench access settings, it says the content type does not have any fields that can be used for access control.

Comment: What does that mean?? @AnkitAgrawal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your permissions in the Admin area for Workbench for each Role at `admin/config/workbench/moderation/check-permissions`

This is a module that has been at 1.0 for a very long time and is mature.

Comment: need to clear the cache. now its working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue where 'Needs Review' tab appeared empty after the workbench moderation state for conten type is set to 'Needs Review' or 'Draft'by the creator.
I applied a patch from drupal.org and it worked. Please find the below patch and apply it in your Workbench Moderation module.

https://www.drupal.org/files/node_revision-1363990-2.patch

Let me know if you still face an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the default View that Workbench Moderation creates? Make sure that no changes have been made that may alter what is displayed in the various Workbench tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Home > Administration> Configuration > Workbench > Workbench Access

Select Require a Workbench Access Form Element[image]

I was using Drupal 7.34 , I also followed the same tutorial link [The tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nqWLrxH_4M&index=9&list=WL)